# Reach into a JavaScript array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If I console log `test`

I get

```
[
    {
            property_1: "a",
            property_2: "b",
    }
]
```

How can I console log the value of `property_1` ?

Comment: What did you try? Did it work? If not, why not?

Comment: Because your question does not show research effort :)

Comment: Not all questions need to be "researched" before been asked. I wanted to keep it simple hence why I did not go into "what I have tried" etc. I also looked around for similar questions but could not find one that matched my question exactly.

Comment: @jamjam: No, you don't need to research, but when you don't, you'll likely get down-voted. Your choice. Also, if you honestly don't know how to access a member of an Array, or a property of an Object, then you really need to read a basic beginner's tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(test[0]["property_1"])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log(test[0].property_1);
```

`test` is an array, who's first element is a map with keys `property_1`, and `property_2`.

`test[0]` accesses the first element of the array, which is a map. From there you can directly access the properties with the dot notation, or with a string subscript:

```
console.log(test[0]["property_1"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

First go into the array:

```
my_arr[0]
```

Then to get the property:

```
my_arr[0]['property_1']
```

End result:

```
var my_arr = [
    {
            property_1: "a",
            property_2: "b",
    }
]

alert(my_arr[0]['property_1']);
```

Answer (score 1):

If that's what you get when you `console.log`, then I'd bet that you have a *JSON string* that needs to be parsed.

If so, do this...

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(test);

alert(parsed[0].property_1);
```

Comment: json string would have quoted property names and not a trailing comma :P

Comment: @Esailija: Well true, but it could still be a string. Are there any consoles that give that sort of output for object structures? I don't use Firebug, so maybe that's how it looks.

Comment: To think about it, logging an actual object wouldn't give trailing commas either. The OP has probably written it by hand.